# I receive the following error : " Can't use method return value in write context "

Tags: php

```php
<?php
   
include("Emp.php");

$Email = $_GET["id"];

User::FileLoader();

$content = "";
foreach (User::$userlist as $user) {
    if ($user->get_Email() == $Email) {
        if ($user->get_State() == 1) {
            $user->set_State() = 0;       
        }
        else if ($user->get_State() == 0) {
            $user->set_State() = 1;
        }
    }
}
header("location:liste.php");
```

Comment: What do you expect `$user->set_State()=0;` to do?. Same question applies to `$user->set_State()=1;` and `whatever_function() = 42;`

Comment: `$user->set_State()=0;` must be `$user->set_State(0);` i guess

Comment: I want to change the user state  it is an object and I want to make a change on it . 
 I tried  $user->set_State(0); but it dose not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message may be a little obtuse, but it's not that hard to understand.  The return value of a function call is just that -- a *value*.  Unlike a variable, it is not backed by persistent storage, so you cannot write to it by, for example, using it as the left-hand operand of an assignment.

Thus, both this ...

> ```
>             $user->set_State() = 0;
> ```

... and this ...

> ```
>             $user->set_State() = 1;
> ```

... are wrong.

You have not presented your `User` class to inform an answer, but surely the `set_State()` method expects you to specify the new state via an argument. For example,

```
            $user->set_State(0);
```

Comment: So what ca i do

Comment: public function get_State()
    {
        return $this->State;
    }
    public function set_State($state)
    {
        return $this->State = $state;
    }

Comment: There is my getters and setter  for it

Comment: @RanalaManaja, refer to "but surely the `set_State()` method expects you to specify the new state via an argument".  And the `set_State()` method you present indeed does expect and use an argument.